Expected value of an estimator of shape parameter of the generalized Pareto distribution
I would like to compute the expected value and variance of the kappa parameter for the generalized Pareto distribution, where
$$
\hat{\kappa} = \frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{{s}}
$$
Where
$$
s = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \hat{\mu})^2
$$
which is second moment.
This is challenging due to the presence of the ratio in the expression.
My questions are:
Is it possible to compute this expected value? If we assume that $\hat{\sigma}$ is unbiased, can we take it outside the expectation and then compute the expected value? How can we solve this problem?
Can it be approximated to a chi-squared distribution?

Did you intend $\hat mu = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and $\hat \sigma^2= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \hat{\mu})^2$?  Can you define the parameters and pdf or CDF of your  generalized Pareto distribution as Wikipedia does not seem to use $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in the way you do.

The parameters μ and  in our context were estimated differently, so they do not correspond directly to the traditional definitions found on Wikipedia.

What Henry is saying is that, since the definition of the distribution you're using does not seem to match a commonly accepted definition, many people who might otherwise be able to help you will not be able to: They won't really know what you're asking. If you provide the information he requested, it will be much clearer what your question is.

But there are other bits that -- to me, anyway -- are most easily explained as an error. For example, when you write "where $\mu = \frac{1}{n}\sum (x_i - \hat{\mu})^2$"... I mean, that really looks like a formula for the thing usually denoted $\hat{\sigma}^2$, not $\mu$. (Never mind that Wikipedia uses $\mu$ for some other thing entirely here.) More to the point, the formula that preceded it doesn't mention $\mu$ -- so this clarification seems relevant only if your readers go through the effort of rewriting it.

Thank you for clarifying. I have made the necessary adjustments. Regarding Henry's suggestion, I have used the same generalized Pareto distribution formula, with the difference lying in the estimation method. I have estimated the parameters using a different approach.

Therefore, I have reached a point where I am unsure how to proceed further. Could I calculate the expected value separately for the numerator and denominator if they are independent? Alternatively, can I extract sigma hat outside of the expectation since I have demonstrated it to be unbiased? Or should I approximate the ratio to a chi-squared distribution?
